# How Implement Pagination

Tags: html

What is the best possible way to implement pagination? Currently, I have a list of items in which I wish to paginate if they're more than 20 items. Any available plugins or tutorials that anyone could point me in the direction to?

Comment: You should explain what are you using in the backend. HTML generated by database through your own script? some CRM? Static HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all that you know is HTML, then you will need a separate page for each.

If you know a server-side technology such as PHP, and have a host that supports it, then you have just one file to generate the HTML dynamically with each reloading

If you know a client-side technology such as Javascript, then you have again have just one file, which will pull-up the pictures dynamically without reloading the HTML.